# Copy column from one array to other column in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$list = [

    {
        "id":67,
        "text":"Brands1",
        "class_3_main":[
            {
                "originalId":12,
                "name":"USA",
                "Id":"1",
                "mainSupplierIds":"23, 24, 32, 21, 39, 84, 23"
            },
            {
                "tag_id":6825,
                "name":"UK",
                "Id":"2307",
                "mainSupplierIds":"47, 11"
            }
        ],
        "class_3_suppliers":[
            {
                "originalId":6927,
                "name":"USA Suppliers",
                "supplierIds":''
            },
            {
                "tag_id":6928,
                "name":"UK Suppliers",
                "supplierIds":
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

I want the column `mainSupplierIds` from the array `class_3_main` to be linked to `supplierIds` for `class_3_suppliers` array.

At the end I expect the output to be:

```
"class_3_suppliers":[
        {
            "originalId":6927,
            "name":"USA Suppliers",
            "supplierIds":'23, 24, 32, 21, 39, 84, 23'
        },
        {
            "tag_id":6928,
            "name":"UK Suppliers",
            "supplierIds":'47, 11'
        }
    ],
```

I was using the below code to achieve this:

```
$result = array_map(create_function('$arr', 'return $arr["mainSupplierIds"];'), $class_3_main);
$class_3_suppliers['supplierIds'] = $result;
```

But the result combines the both supplierIds and the resukt returned is

```
"class_3_suppliers":[
    {
        "originalId":6927,
        "name":"USA Suppliers",
        "supplierIds":[
            0: '23, 24, 32, 21, 39, 84, 23',
            1: '47,11'
        ]
    },
    {
        "tag_id":6928,
        "name":"UK Suppliers",
        "supplierIds":[
            0: '23, 24, 32, 21, 39, 84, 23',
            1: '47,11'
        ]
    } ],
```

Comment: your array looks like a json string to me

Answer (score 1):

If this is supposed to be a PHP object with these values and they will always have the same names for the properties with the ID's and the same amount in both class_3_main and class_3_suppliers then this can work.

```
$list = [
    "id"=>67,
    "text"=>"Brands1",
    "class_3_main"=>[[
            "originalId"=>12,
            "name"=>"USA",
            "Id"=>"1",
            "mainSupplierIds"=>"23, 24, 32, 21, 39, 84, 23"
        ],
        [
            "tag_id"=>6825,
            "name"=>"UK",
            "Id"=>"2307",
            "mainSupplierIds"=>"47, 11"
        ]
    ],
    "class_3_suppliers"=>[
        [
            "originalId"=>6927,
            "name"=>"USA Suppliers",
            "supplierIds"=>""
        ],
        [
            "tag_id"=>6928,
            "name"=>"UK Suppliers",
            "supplierIds"=>""
        ]
    ]
];

$class3Mains = $list["class_3_main"];
$class3Suppliers = $list["class_3_suppliers"];
$index = 0;

foreach($class3Mains as $class3Main) {
    $class3Suppliers[$index]["supplierIds"] = $class3Main["mainSupplierIds"];
    $index++;
}

var_dump($class3Suppliers);
```

You take out the array from class_3_main and class_3_suppliers and loop them and copy the value from one property to the other.
The script I have added can be tested here: http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: it had woked, sorry for late reply